# Do you square root first or multiply first in this sentence? Thanks!

Tags: meaning

It is not a math question, because the text I have some questions about is like this:

> The number is not less than the round down of square root of the total
> quantity*1.5.

I have searched by Google and on this site, but I haven’t got the answer. If the quoted sentence refers to the total quantity*1.5 before we square root the result, how do we write ‘square root(the total quantity) *1.5’ in English in a text?

I can’t reach any friends knowing both math and English well enough to help me solve this question, and I don’t know the one who wrote the quoted sentence either. Therefore, I sincerely want to get help from you. Thanks a lot!

This is the context in case you need, as the following sentence has appeared before the quoted sentence above:

> Number is not less than the round down of square root of the total quantity.

Update: the writer means square root first, then multiply, and then round down

Thank all of you!

Comment: The 'total quantity' sounds like a measure, in which case it can't have a square root. You'd need 'the round down of the square root of the number expressing the mass in kg' etc. And the closer an operation is to that number in running text (the number coming last), the earlier it needs to be carried out. Hence y ≥ x where x = [√m] or ⌊√m⌋, depending on your choice of symbol, with m the numerical value denoting mass in kg. This will itself be a rounded figure. // Using *1·5 is not admissible in running text. There is a conflict in rules of precedence here. Why not use maths symbols?

Comment: I can see that there may have been reasons for closing this question (perhaps that it is, in the old terminology of this site, too localised), but it is hard to see what 'details of clarity' it needs. The question is a perfectly clear request for clarification of an unclear text; its being about an unclear text does not make the question itself unclear.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! You are wonderful! In fact, I agree with many of you that my quoted sentence is not a sentence written in standard English. Therefore, perhaps my question should be may I know the proper way to write ‘square root(the total quantity) *1.5’ and ‘square root(the total quantity*1.5)’ in English in a text respectively without causing confusion. And perhaps that’s a question without answer? Anyway, thank all of you!

Comment: I also understand the need for more information because I have omitted some classified terms to avoid violating my non-disclosure agreements with my company. However, I can assure you that all I have omitted is not of help for understanding the sentence. Thanks!

Comment: Mathematical operations described ambiguously, like the above, cannot be correctly interpreted with any confidence. The recommended method is to ask the author. If that is impossible, maybe provide more context, so that a math person can reliably figure out what is meant. Can you tell us what the final result is supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous, but it does seem more likely that the multiplication is intended to happen before the square root. If you wanted to force the other interpretation, you could reword the sentence as follows:

> The number is not less than the round down of 1.5 times the square root of the total quantity.

Answer (score 0):

The question has multiple possible meanings, as multiplying by 1.5 could be done first, or after taking the square root, or after performing the round down. It could have been written clearly as

> the product of 1.5 and the round down of the square root of the total quantity

or

> the round down of the product of 1.5 and the square root of the total quantity

or

> the round down of the square root of the product of 1.5 and the total quantity.

I agree with @alphabet that the last meaning is the most likely, but there is no certainty.

Comment: Oh thank you! You gave me a third possibility. May I know how do you write  ‘square root(the total quantity) *1.5’ and ‘square root(the total quantity*1.5)’ in English in a text respectively for reference? Thank you so much! Have a nice day!

Comment: Oh I mean, in a shorter way? If you think you have already answered, that’s great too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that there isn't an answer, in fact the sentence as it stands is not even good English grammar:

> The number is not less than the round down of *the* square root of the total
> quantity*1.5.

"round down" is not a term I am familiar with as a noun, though I assume it means the rounded down value of ...

However, English is not precise and unambiguous as mathematical notation is, and so there are several possible meanings here:

- round(sqrt(total_quantity*1.5))
- round(sqrt(total_quantity)*1.5)
- round(sqrt(total_Quantity))*1.5

Which it is I think is impossible to say. So you'd have to go to the source for clarification.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I do need to go to the writer. I will try and hopefully I can update what the writer wanted to express on this post. Have a good day!

Answer (score -1):

The [order of operations](https://www.edweek.org/teaching-learning/opinion-please-excuse-my-dear-aunt-sally-pemdas-forever/2011/01) says perform the square root first:

**P**lease **E**xcuse **M**y **D**ear **A**unt **S**ally who is **N**ice and **O**ld.

1. Parentheses
2. **Exponentiation**
3. Multiplication & Division equally
4. Addition & Subtraction equally
5. Not
6. Or

Comment: That applies to mathematical formulae, not to written text.

Comment: Oh thank you! That’s partly why I have doubts about my quoted sentence. May I know how do you write  ‘square root(the total quantity) *1.5’ and ‘square root(the total quantity*1.5)’ in English in a text respectively for reference? Thank you so much! Have a nice day!

Comment: In Math, word problems carry the weight of numerical expressions. The point of PEDMAS is precisely to address ambiguity.

Comment: A = " ... the square root of the total quantity, then times 1.5." B = " ... the square root of 1.5 times the total quantity."

Comment: Thank you! It is clear!

Comment: 'The square root of four multiplied by nine' is ill-defined in standard English, where BIDMAS doesn't apply. In an oral arithmetic test, _arithmetic_ (sequential) _logic_ rather than _algebraic logic_ would be expected, often represented in mathsscript by operations over arrows.

Comment: The point of PEDMAS is to disambiguate mathematical expressions like 5·3+2·7 and 6·4/12·3; it only applies to English words when somebody is reading a mathematical expression aloud.